# Can't add fund to PSN wallet with a US credit card while accessing from outside U.S

Tags: psn

I just moved to Hong Kong recently for work. I have a valid US credit card but I can't seem to add fund to my PSN wallet. Does Sony even stipulate that I have to be in US to use my US credit card? I didn't recall there's a ***money region lock*** in their term of use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work from the store online? I think you can add funds through there too. Also region locking *money* is beyond stupid

Comment: Try adding funds through the SEN site: https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.action?service-entity=psn

Comment: After logging in, go to Account -> Wallet and try adding funds with your card. If it still locks you out through that site, I would try masking your IP to appear to be in the US (easier to do on a browser than on the PS3)

Comment: @BenBrocka It works, but I have to mask my IP to do it, otherwise I got "your credit card information is incorrect", quite a subtle message than "we do not accept your dollar coming outside of United States!" If all PS3 discs are region free, there's no point to region lock the PSN store and DLC. But how PSN store region lock lead to money region lock is beyond me.

Comment: @JohnoBoy Thanks for the suggestion. Masking IP is a must but you need to watch out potential security threat. VPN is best for this.

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty horrible error message. At least you figured out the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to JohnoBoy, the solution to Sony's ridiculous ***money region lock*** is twofold:

1. **masking your IP to make it look like it is coming from US.** I did it with VPN, which is the most secured way to do it since your are accessing your private PSN account that also contains your credit card information. I don't recommend proxy servers because some free proxy servers keep log of people's information and sell them to third party. It could help others to compromise your PSN account and your credit card.
2. **Add funds through [SEN website](https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.action) under "Account -> Wallet".** This new online feature is probably the most useful thing that Sony did to their dinosaur PSN website.

**An alternative is to buy PSN cards codes from Amazon* or [Maximus cards](http://www.maximuscards.com/).** They both email you the code instantly and thankfully Sony don't region lock the PSN card.

***NOTE:** Amazon only require you to provide a US billing address, even with a non-US card. This has been tested by JohnoBoy. The plus side with Amazon is that they don't charge extra on top of the face value of the PSN card. They actually give you 1 cent off. Maximus cards on the other hand charges $2.49 ~ $8.59 extra for a single card, depending on the face value of the card you are buying.

Comment: Welcome to the brave new world of idiotic region restrictions.

Comment: Just so you know, you can buy PSN codes off Amazon as long as you use a US billing address, even with a non-US card. You don't have to mask your IP, I've done this in the past several times